# Problem with ad-hoc evaluation in rest api instance

Tags: javascript, marklogic-9

I am new to MarkLogic and I am trying to evaluate some javascript code thorough an REST client api instance.

Using OutSystems' http request sending tool, I am sending to HTTP request like bellow.
[image]

as you can see in the picture, bellow javascript code was sent in Body.

```
xdmp.directory("/character/","1")
```

Destination API resource is ****:port/v1/eval

However, bellow error message was respond.
[image]

Does javascript code have some problem??
Do I have to re-write some appropriate code?

Or is this because of an authentication problem??

My purpose of evaluating thhis code is to get the all documents in a database.

Anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

To get all the docs in the database, you're probably better off using [MarkLogic Content Pump](https://developer.marklogic.com/products/mlcp)'s export feature. But to answer your original question, take a look at the example at the bottom of the docs for [POST /v1/eval](http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/POST/v1/eval); you'll see the following in the first example:

```
$ cat body.sjs
javascript=
xdmp.arrayValues([word1, word2, word1 %2B " " %2B word2])
&
vars={"word1":"hello","word2":"world"}
```

`body.sjs` is the body of the message sent to MarkLogic. Note the `javascript=` at the beginning.

Comment: Hi, Dave

Thank you for your help. I'll try both.